# SQL Show 0 Values when no values between date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have some problems with my sql query. 
Im selecting some values with a specific date range.
for example 2018-05-01 to 2018-05-13 this is the output.

```
SUM  CalendarWeek
8    18
5    19
```

If the user will select now a date between 2018-04-01 and 2018-05-13 i want to show a 0 instead when there are no values.

For example:

```
SUM  CalendarWeek
0    13
0    14
0    15
0    16
0    17
8    18
5    19
```

My Query:

```
SELECT SUM(Codes) AS 'Sum', CW FROM(
SELECT Count(*) AS 'Codes', DATEPART(wk, ScanDate) AS 'CW',
FROM [Table]
WHERE CONVERT(date, ScanDate, 102) >= '2018-01-01' AND CONVERT(date, ScanDate, 102) <= '2018-05-13' 
GROUP BY ScanDate,  DATEPART(wk, ScanDate) 
UNION ALL 
SELECT Count(*) AS 'Codes', DATEPART(wk, ScanDate) AS 'CW', ScanDate
FROM [Table_Archive] 
WHERE CONVERT(date, ScanDate, 102) >= '2018-01-01' AND CONVERT(date, ScanDate, 102) <= '2018-05-13'
GROUP BY ScanDate, DATEPART(wk, ScanDate)) test 
GROUP BY CW, ScanDate
ORDER BY CW ASC
```

any ideas how to solve this? 
Thanks

Comment: Show your code that produces the sum/calendar week results.

Comment: SQL is not good at making up data that does not exist,. So you either need to have a date table that you can LEFT JOIN to the actual data, or add rows in the display layer

Comment: @Afer you still need to clarify your question.  Are you saying that when the user selects a date range of two weeks, you want it to return a date range of seven weeks?

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to maintain calender table for such kind of task. If, so then use them. else would need to use *recursive* cte

```
declare @stardate date, @enddate date

set @stardate = '2018-04-01' 
set @enddate = '2018-05-13'

with t as (
    select DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, @stardate) as CalendarWeek
    union all
    select CalendarWeek+1
    from t
    where CalendarWeek < DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, @enddate)
)
select t1.sum, coalesce(t.CalendarWeek, 0) CalendarWeek
from t
left join table t1 on t1.CalendarWeek = t.CalendarWeek
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM, 0), CalendarWeek
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to explain it better. If the user select 2018-04-01 to 2018-05-13 the result will be like my first example. Only 2 Calendarweeks will be shown. because there are no other CW

Comment: @Afer I'm a little confused as well because the first statement is only requesting two calendar weeks - there's only two weeks in the date range.

Comment: @Afer put it in the original post.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `IF` in MySQL:

```
Select  IF(sum=null, 0,sum) as sum from table_name
```

If you don't find solution now from this you can comment again I will give the exact query

Comment: In this case you don't want or need to use conditional statements.  It's done for you, and it's faster to use ISNULL().

Comment: yes ofcourse but you can not vote negative for this its also a solution everyone has its own path .if you stuck some where then every solution is the solution . Thanks

Comment: `IF` I were to down vote your solution, it would be because it references MySQL when the OP's question relates to T-SQL/MSSQL.

Comment: In question it is saying mysql. Anyway thnx